# MVC3 Recreate Tables

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm making a MVC3 C# application and I wanted to clear all the tables and basically start fresh. I went into the SQL Server Object Explorer and deleted all the tables that I was using for my models. Now I was hoping they would be created again and empty next time I build.. unfortunately that isn't the case. How can I get my application to recreate the tables?

Comment: Don't you have a back up of your database?

Comment: Are you using Code First to rebuild your tables?  If you're not, you possibly just lost all of your DB, unless of course you have backups.

Comment: I don't care about the data in the database I just want that database to work again as new. Yeah I'm using code first.